# App only for iPhones not iPod. (like Whatsapp)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, ipod

I have been googling from few days like when we goto AppStore in **iPod** and try installing '**Whatsapp**' it shows a pop-up with message :

```
"This app is not compatible with your device."
```

[image]

So my question is, being a **Developer** how do we do this ? Where this can be set somewhere within our application build or itunesconnect or some where else ? Howw ?

Any suggestions will be helpful. :)

Comment: you can set the app would require the _phone_ capabilities and that does the trick for you; let this be your guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that by changing the required capability of a device. For instance, an app with telephony requirement will only work on iPhone. Check this [Apple iOS device compatibility reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html)

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this is to include for the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities entry (a dictionary), the telephony key with a value of YES, meaning, only devices that support telephony can use the app.

Also, check out the [complete reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) of what keys are available for use with UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities.

[image: Secreenshot]